# AWS CodeBuild DOWNLOAD_SOURCE failed - CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: amazon-web-services, cicd, aws-codebuild

I always get the following failure message whenever my build is triggered via a GitHub webhook in CodeBuild:

> CLIENT_ERROR: open /codebuild/output/srcDownload/src/.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/pre-promo: is a directory for primary source and source version 2f1537e75dbe4c83437c75560ca1dae5a9f475e0

[DOWNLOAD_SOURCE CLIENT_ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpvcV.png)

My source code is in GitHub and my webhook build is triggered on merges that match the BASE_REF pattern: `^refs/heads/feature/[a-z-]+/base$`.

[Primary source webhook events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7kU3.png)

Additionally, if I kick off a manual build there are no issues.

I've tried disconnecting from GitHub and reconnecting but this hasn't worked. I've tried configuring the VPC thinking it could be related but it's the same with or without one.

**Update 14/03/23**

I've since tried the following BASE_REF pattern `^refs/heads/feature/pre-promo/base$` but get the exact same error. I've tried recreating the CodeBuild project but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Can you pull code from github using the access token you set in CodeBuild?

Comment: @HùngNguyễn Sorry should have mentioned I'm currently connected to GitHub using OAuth. Manual builds work fine where I manually specify the branch.